# Android Chrome connects to wrong directory when using VPS server

Tags: wordpress, apache, ubuntu-18.04, vps

I know that this can be silly question with a simple answer but I am new with hosting a VPS server and learning things, so forgive my ignorance. My problem is that I have set up a VPS server and I am hosting my own WordPress site and everything else seems to go smooth but when I am trying to see my webpage using phone it will show var/www/ directory instead of home/mydomain/public_html content like with windows any browser. I have checked my apache2 .conf file and the directories there seems to be right. Can't find anything similar by googling so do you have any ideas how to start to tackle this issue?

Comment: Did you try to purge cache on a phone?

Comment: It had something to do with directory indexing and after disabling that and purging cache everything started to work smooth. Thank you for your answer.